# Ant read a property file from within a zip file

Tags: ant, properties, zip

Is there a way in ant to load properties from inside a zip file?

I have a project ant file which needs to use some properties that are in a file that is inside a zip file. The zip file is stored in a known location on our CI server.

```
/known location/file.zip
   |
   +--- properties/details.properties
```

The following doesn't work

```
<project name="test" basedir="." >
    <property file="/known location/file.zip/properties/details.properties"/>
    ....
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since zip files and jar files are basically the same, you can use the `url` form of the `property` task, with a `jar` url.

```
<property url="jar:file:/known location/file.zip!/properties/details.properties" />
```

Note the `jar:file:` at the front of the url, and the `!/` separating the zip file location from the path of the properties file within the zip.

See the [JarURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) docs for more info on the syntax of a `jar:` url.

Comment: This approach is cleaner than the unzip approach, though both work.

Answer (score 1):

you could unzip the file to a temp location and then load the unzipped properties file

```
<target name="load-zipped-props">
    <unzip src="${propfile-name}.zip" dest="${unzip-destination}" />
    <property file="${unzip-destination}/${propfile-name}.properties"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just have to make sure that every target that needs the properties has a dependency on the load-zipped-props target.

Comment: yes, you probably want to add some code to delete the unzipped file, if it exists already, before unzipping it